# Golang parse XML with nested nodes of the same name?

Tags: xml, go, parsing

I need to parse xml code,

```
<claims>
    <claim>
        <claim-text>ABC
            <claim-text>PQR</claim-text>
            <claim-text>Xyz
                <claim-text>A</claim-text>
                <claim-text>B</claim-text>
                <claim-text>C</claim-text>
            </claim-text>
        </claim-text>
    </claim>
    <claim>
        <claim-text>PPP
            <claim-text>ZZZ</claim-text>
            <claim-text>MMM</claim-text>
        </claim-text>
    </claim>
```

How to get array of 'claim' with inside all claim texts?
I was trying this but it does not give whatever text enclosed in claim-text.

```
type Result struct {
Claims  []Claim `xml:"claims>claim"`
}
type Claim struct{
  ClaimText []string `xml:"claim-text"` 
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```golang
type Result struct {
    Claims []Claim `xml:"claim"`
}

type Claim struct {
    ClaimText []ClaimText `xml:"claim-text"`
}

type ClaimText struct {
    Value     string      `xml:",chardata"`
    ClaimText []ClaimText `xml:"claim-text"`
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/uueAiwG84LH

---

If you want to get rid of the white-space, you can implement the unmarshaler interface:

```golang
func (t *ClaimText) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    type T ClaimText
    if err := d.DecodeElement((*T)(t), &start); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    t.Value = strings.TrimSpace(t.Value)
    return nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/2I1meeBm0pu

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [online tool](https://www.onlinetool.io/xmltogo/) that generate the following struct:

```
type Claims struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"claims"`
    Text    string   `xml:",chardata"`
    Claim   []struct {
        Text      string `xml:",chardata"`
        ClaimText struct {
            Text      string `xml:",chardata"`
            ClaimText []struct {
                Text      string   `xml:",chardata"`
                ClaimText []string `xml:"claim-text"`
            } `xml:"claim-text"`
        } `xml:"claim-text"`
    } `xml:"claim"`
}
```